# No encuentro el problema con la siguiente sintaxis utilizando function

Tags: function

tengo que hacer la resolución a un problema de si puede subir o no una persona a una atraccion en un parque, pero encuentro que me manda un resultado que dice "Una persona con estatura de 1.2, que no lleva a un adulto y que no tiene problemas cardíacos puede subir a la atracción (1.2, false, false), debe devolver false"
Pero simplemente no veo donde se comete un error, diría que es la sintaxis pero soy bastante nuevo  para decirlo con seguridad. Estas son las condiciones:

1. Alcanzar una altura mínima de 1.5m (o 1.2m si está acompañada por un
   adulto)
2. No tener ningún problema cardíaco

A continuación el código que realice:

```
function puedeSubirse(alturaP, vieneConCompania, tieneproblemasCardiacos){
    return ((alturaP >= 1.5 && vieneConCompania == true || vieneConCompania == false && tieneproblemasCardiacos == false) || (alturaP >= 1.2 && vieneConCompania == true && tieneproblemasCardiacos == false));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es más fácil y más legible si lo haces con condiciones separadas:

```js
function puedeSubirse(alturaP, vieneConCompania, tieneproblemasCardiacos){
      
      // nadie sube con problemas cardiacos
        if(tieneproblemasCardiacos) return false
        
      // si tiene altura minima o esta acompañado puede subir
        if(alturaP >= 1.5  || (alturaP < 1.5 && vieneConCompania)) return true
      
      // por defecto 
      return false
    }
    
 console.log(puedeSubirse(1.5, false, false));
```

Comment: Gracias! tienes toda la razón, es mas entendible de esta manera.